# Were there any Russians in the Atlantis expedition?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

We know that Russia was the second country to be involved in the Stargate program, long before any other nation had been made aware of it.

We know that the Atlantis expedition was supervised by the IOA, hence the members have been selected from several different countries.

Although there were some unlucky events with Russian nationals involved in the Stargate program, I believe that they would still like to have someone in the Atlantis expedition, especially when they know that the expedition and its discoveries may be unavailable for the Stargate Command (and therefore Russia) for some time due to problems with communications, even if they preferred to sit in the back, read reports, and watch.

Were there any Russian nationals in the Atlantis expedition? Is lack of them ever referred to in the series? Are there any in-/out-of-universe reasons why there weren't any?

Comment: I don't remember anyone being explicitly called out on their nationality, apart from McKay talking about being Canadian.  IIRC, everyone had a shoulder patch of the flag of their home country, so you could re-watch and look for Russian flags.

Comment: From what I remember there are Canadian, Scottish, Czech, and Spanish flags on uniforms. I do not remember Russian flags, that's why I ask, instead of watching the whole series again :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is at least one. Here is a screenshot from 17:06 in s1e01: Rising (part 1).

[image: Russian member of Atlantis team (1)]

At this point, the characters are still in the SGC. However, I think only Atlantis team members have flags on their arm. Moreover, the same character can be seen waiting to go through the gate, at 21:23.

[image]

Comment: I have rewatched this episode with my SO yesterday and I told her that I'm going to answer my own question, however, you were faster :)

Answer (score 4):

**According to the [Stargate Wikia](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_nations_of_the_Atlantis_Committee), Yes**

The list of countries appearing in the show, taken from the above link: Australia, Belgium, Canada, China, Czech Republic, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Italy, Jamaica, Japan, Kurdistan, New Zealand, Philippines, Poland, Portugal, **Russia**, Serbia, South Africa, South Korea, Spain, Sweden, Turkey, United Kingdom, Scotland, United States and Zimbabwe.

That source, unfortunately, does list in which episode(s) Russian members of the Atlantis expedition appear, nor their name. The [Russia](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Russia) page in the Wikia laconically states that Russia "also sent personnel to Atlantis".

On this [forum](https://forum.gateworld.net/threads/26159-Different-Nationalities-in-Atlantis/page9), the member Harlan listed the flags appearing in the pilot episode *Rising* and a Russian appears amongst other nationalities.

Note: I don't know these sources well and cannot state how trustworthy they are. IMDB does not list any Russian-sounding name for that episode.

Comment: Wikis are a very poor source of info.  I could just as easily go and edit it to make your answer invalid